# Moving magento page titles to a new place

Tags: magento-1.9, page-title

I'm working on a magento website and would like to move all titles to another place(See images for an example).

**Right now it looks like this**

https://puu.sh/x2bGu/4d47221c65.jpg

**It must look like this**

https://puu.sh/x2buz/36bf62ecf5.jpg

It's need to be done for the following templates. (1column and 2columns-left templates)

How can i place the magento titles to a new block??

Comment: Your Magento version ?

Comment: Magento ver. 1.9.3.0

Answer (score 1):

If I am not wrong it can be achieved with using magento vars, more specifically the PHP logic that echoes out the page title:

It would be something like:

```
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->getTitle();
```

or

```
<?php echo str_replace(Mage::getStoreConfig('design/head/title_prefix'), '', $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->getTitle()); ?>
```

Then use the following code in our template file. eg

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/html/head.phtml
```

Comment: Sadly it isn't working for all pages.  
For sub pages like: (category page, subcategory page, product page,   etc) it shows the entire path eg: Home -> main category -> Sub category

i only need the last part of the title (sub category title)